# C++ Read Integers from file splitted by column

Tags: c++

I have a 1 line txt file full of ints splitted by column and I want to push the numbers into an Int array

```
1,9,6,4,5
```

Here's my work

```
int main()
{
int A[100],n = 0;
string read;

ifstream file("input.txt");

stringstream str(read);

while(getline(file, read)){
    stringstream str(read);
}

for(int i;str >> i;) {
    A[n] = i;
    n++;
    if (str.peek() == ',')
        str.ignore();
}

for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    cout<<A[i]<<",";
}
cout<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this loop body

```
while(getline(file, read)){
    stringstream str(read);
}
```

You are creating a new object `str` and it is discarded at the end of this loop body.

Instead of this, you have to set the data in the previously created object `str`.

It can be done using [`str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) function.

```
while(getline(file, read)){
    str.str(read);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't have much sense . `.str()` resets a stream

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин This seems working [in my test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xVxTfNAIdlo5Z2vG). Please give me some more detail.

Comment: you'll have last string only

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин The input is "a 1 line txt file" here. What doesn't have much sense is the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read from `str` only after reaching the end of file. But as you have only one line, you could use `getline` to split on commas, and then a `stringstream` to convert each field to an int:

```
int A[100], n = 0;                              // do not forget to initialize n
while(getline(file, read, ',')){
    stringstream str(read);
    str >> A[n];
    if (++n > sizeof (A)/sizeof (*A)) break;    // do not go past sizeof(A)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    std::fstream fa("b" ,std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
    std::stringstream mj;
    std::vector <int> x;

    fa >> mj.rdbuf();  
    do
    {
        mj >> *x.insert(x.end(), (int)NULL);
        mj.ignore(200, ',');
    }while (mj.eof() == false);

    std::cout << "and then " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << " " << x[3] << " size "<< x.size() << std::endl;
}
```